# How programmatically (!) validate soap request/response with wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, validation, soap, wsdl

Suppose I have an xml file with request/response and wsdl file. How I can validate *request/response by wsdl*?

**Important**

I know that it is possible to enable such validation with container like Spring-Ws or Metro, but I want manual validation without container like that:

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
     File xmlRequest = new File(arg[0]);
     File wsdlFile = new File(arg[1]);
     //....
     someValidator.validate(xmlRequest, wsdlFile);
}
```

Comment: This would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952387/how-to-set-wsdl-inner-schema-to-jaxb2marshaller-to-validate-each-post-i-wold-mak

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate an xml, you need to create an XSD for that xml.

After that is just a call to a validate method, just like you did.

```
package com.journaldev.xml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("EmployeeRequest.xml validates against Employee.xsd? "+validateXMLSchema("Employee.xsd", "EmployeeRequest.xml"));
      System.out.println("EmployeeResponse.xml validates against Employee.xsd? "+validateXMLSchema("Employee.xsd", "EmployeeResponse.xml"));
      System.out.println("employee.xml validates against Employee.xsd? "+validateXMLSchema("Employee.xsd", "employee.xml"));

      }

    public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath){

        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = 
                    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here a tutorial:**

http://www.journaldev.com/895/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-in-java

Comment: I need valiadtion request/response by wsdl. Question has been updated.