# How to set wsdl inner schema to Jaxb2Marshaller to validate each post i wold make?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, validation, wsdl

I'm consuming a SOAP webservice where I have to validate every xml post before call it.

So I'm using:

- The **cxf-codegen-plugin** to generate the POJO tree structure.
- A third part wsdl (xxxx-soap-service.wsdl)
- A class implementing **WebServiceGatewaySupport** spring interface to make the calls.
- **Jaxb2Marshaller** spring marshaller/unmarshaller to convert pojo <··> xml

Well, the code fragments now I have:

- **applicationContext-xxxx-base.xml**:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
                          http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd">

      <mybatis:scan base-package="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.mybatis.mapper" />

      <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.integration.remo" />

      <bean id="xxxxMarshallerProperties" class="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.properties.XxxxMarshallerProperties"/>

      <bean id="xxxxMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" depends-on="xxxxMarshallerProperties">
          <property name="contextPath" value="#{xxxxMarshallerProperties.contextPath}"/>
          <property name="validationEventHandler" value="#{xxxxMarshallerProperties.validationEventHandler}"/>
          <property name="schema" value="#{xxxxMarshallerProperties.schema}"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="xxxxService" class="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.client.XxxxServiceImpl">
          <property name="defaultUri" value="#{'${xxxx.baseUrl}' + '${xxxx.url.sufix}'}" />
          <property name="marshaller" ref="xxxxMarshaller" />
          <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xxxxMarshaller" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="xxxxObjectFactory" class="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.model.ObjectFactory" />


  </beans>
  ```

  - **XxxxMarshallerProperties**, to configure marshaller/unmarshaller bean:

    //
    @Component
    public class XxxxMarshallerProperties {
        @Autowired
        private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    ```
    public Resource getSchema() throws IOException, SAXException {
        WebServiceClient wscAnnotation = Service.class.getAnnotation(WebServiceClient.class);
        String wsdlLocationPath = wscAnnotation.wsdlLocation();
        Resource wsdlResource = resourceLoader.getResource(wsdlLocationPath);
        final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        URI wsdlUri = wsdlResource.getURI();
        Source[] streamSources = new Source[] { new StreamSource(wsdlUri.toString()) };
        final Schema wsdlSchema = schemaFactory.newSchema(streamSources);
        return wsdlSchema;
    }

    public DefaultValidationEventHandler getValidationEventHandler() {
        return new DefaultValidationEventHandler();
    }

    public String getContextPath() {
        return XXXXX.class.getPackage().getName();
    }
    ```

    }
  - The **xxxxService** bean class used to call the webservice:

    public class XxxxServiceImpl extends WebServiceGatewaySupport implements ServiceSoap {

    ```
    @Autowired
    XxxxProperties xxxxProperties;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory xxxxObjectFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    private String getActionUrl(String actionName) {
        return xxxxProperties.getActionNamespace() + actionName;
    }

    public CXXXX callXXXX(CallXXXX request) {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = (Jaxb2Marshaller) getMarshaller();
        Result result = new StringResult();

        CallXXXXResponse response = (CallXXXXResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request,
            new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

                public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
                    ((SoapMessage) message).setSoapAction(getActionUrl(xxxxProperties.getSoapActionCallXXXX()));
                }
            });
        return response.getCallXXXXResult();
    }
    ```

    }
  - *xxxxObjectFactory* is a bean from an autogenerated cxf class used to create pojos where store request data values.

  My intention is to attach the wsdl (**xxxx-soap-service.wsdl**) to the marshaller (**xxxxMarshaller**) in order to check the xml generated by it, against the contained schema in wsdl, before the call is make.

  I'm facing the problem that if I simply attach the wsdl (in bean definition through schema property), Jaxb2Marshaller seems consider it as an xsd and gives me back an *org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-elt-schema-ns: 'definitions' namespace  must be...*

  I'm now trying to extract the inner xsd from the wsdl and attach it to the marshaller, but the xsd it has to be a **org.springframework.core.io.Resource** to do that. That's because my code not compile yet.

  I have seen that for **JaxbMarshaller** (not Jaxb**2**Marshaller) this is possible.

So could you help me in that way?

I'm open to explore other ways or better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found an implementation that works for me.

The idea is:

- to extract the embedded schema's from the wsdl,
- configure each schema namespace,
- adding all posible namespaces non defined yet in it but that are defined on <wsdl:definition> tag,
- configure each schema import and locations,
- store each schema into an implementing class of spring's Resource interface,
- store all of them into an Resource array
- and pass this array to the Jaxb2Marshaller through **setSchema[s]**, instead of **setSchema** (as I have been doing).

Based on the question, I had to modify the **XxxxMarshallerProperties** class and the **applicationContext-xxxx-base.xml** files, only.

**XxxxMarshallerProperties**:

```
@Component
public class XxxxMarshallerProperties {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    /**
     * @return A new transformer.
     * @throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError
     * @throws TransformerConfigurationException
     */
    private Transformer newTransformer()
        throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerConfigurationException {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        return transformer;
    }

    /**
     * Load the wsdl into a dom Document. Used at:<br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>getSchemas</b>
     *
     * @param wsdlUrl
     *            url where the WSDL is located at
     * @param transformer
     *            used to load the document
     * @return The wsdl dom Document
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws TransformerException
     */
    private Document loadWsdlDoc(URL wsdlUrl, Transformer transformer)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, TransformerException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder schemaBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document wsdlDoc = schemaBuilder.newDocument();
        BufferedReader wsdlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(wsdlUrl.openStream()));
        Source source = new StreamSource(wsdlReader);
        transformer.transform(source, new DOMResult(wsdlDoc));
        return wsdlDoc;
    }

    /**
     * Store into a map all namespaces defined on the wsdl. Used at:<br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>getSchemas</b>
     *
     * @param defNode
     *            &lt;<b><i>wsdl:definitions</i></b>&gt; dom node where to look
     *            up.
     * @return A map of namespace definition attributes. Format: [(nodeName,
     *         node)....]
     */
    private Map<String, Node> getWsdlDefinedNamespaces(Element defNode) {
        Map<String, Node> namespaces = new TreeMap<>();
        NamedNodeMap defNodeAtt = defNode.getAttributes();
        int defNodeAttSz = defNodeAtt.getLength();
        for (int attIndex = 0; attIndex < defNodeAttSz; attIndex++) {
            String ns = defNodeAtt.item(attIndex).getPrefix();
            if ("xmlns".equals(ns)) {
                namespaces.put(//
                    defNodeAtt.item(attIndex).getNodeName(), //
                    defNodeAtt.item(attIndex));
            }
        }

        return namespaces;
    }

    /**
     * Store into a map all the atributes present in a xsd schema node. Used at:
     * <br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>addDefinitionNamespaces</b>
     *
     * @param wsdlSchemaNode
     *            &lt;<b><i>s:schema</i></b>&gt; dom node where to look up.
     * @return A map of attributes. Format: [(nodeName, node)....]
     */
    private Map<String, Node> getCurrentSchemaAtt(Node wsdlSchemaNode) {
        Map<String, Node> schemaXmlnss = new HashMap<>();

        NamedNodeMap schemaNodeAtt = wsdlSchemaNode.getAttributes();
        int schemaNodeAttSz = schemaNodeAtt.getLength();
        for (int attIndex = 0; attIndex < schemaNodeAttSz; attIndex++) {
            String nodeAttName = schemaNodeAtt.item(attIndex).getNodeName();
            Node nodeAtt = ((NamedNodeMap) schemaNodeAtt).item(attIndex);
            schemaXmlnss.put(nodeAttName, nodeAtt);
        }
        return schemaXmlnss;
    }

    /**
     * Adds all non existing namespace definition attributes to a schema node in
     * that schema node. If a namespace definition attribute name is found into
     * schema node, it's not added to the current schema node attributes. Used
     * at: <br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>getSchemas</b>
     *
     * @param schemaNode
     *            &lt;<b><i>s:schema</i></b>&gt; dom node where to add the
     *            namespace definition attributes.
     * @param namespaces
     *            map storing all namespace definition attributes.
     */
    private void addDefinitionNamespaces(Node schemaNode, Map<String, Node> namespaces) {
        Map<String, Node> currSchemaAttMap = getCurrentSchemaAtt(schemaNode);
        for (Node xmlns : namespaces.values()) {
            String nodeName = xmlns.getNodeName();
            if (!currSchemaAttMap.containsKey(nodeName)) {
                String namespaceURI = xmlns.getNamespaceURI();
                String nodeValue = xmlns.getNodeValue();
                ((Element) schemaNode).setAttributeNS(namespaceURI, nodeName, nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update schema location by adding path. Used at: <br/>
     * &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>getSchemas</b>
     *
     * @param schemaNode
     *            &lt;<b><i>s:schema</i></b>&gt; dom node to update its
     *            location.
     * @return The updated schema.
     */
    private DOMSource updateSchemaLocationByAddingPath(Node schemaNode) {
        DOMSource schemaDomSource = new DOMSource(schemaNode);
        NodeList noteList = schemaDomSource.getNode().getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < noteList.getLength(); j++) {
            if ("xsd:import".equals(noteList.item(j).getNodeName())) {
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = noteList.item(j).getAttributes();
                for (int attIndex = 0; attIndex < nodeMap.getLength(); attIndex++) {
                    if ("schemaLocation".equals(nodeMap.item(attIndex).getNodeName())) {
                        nodeMap.item(attIndex).setNodeValue(nodeMap.item(attIndex).getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return schemaDomSource;
    }

    /**
     * Transform a DOMSource schema into a spring's {@link Resource} to be
     * attached to a {@link Jaxb2Marshaller}.
     *
     * @param schemaDomSource
     *            The schema to be transformed.
     * @param transformer
     *            The transformer used.
     * @return A spring's {@link Resource} interface.
     * @throws TransformerException
     */
    private Resource transformToResource(DOMSource schemaDomSource, Transformer transformer)
        throws TransformerException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Result result = new StreamResult(outStream);
        transformer.transform(schemaDomSource, result);
        ByteArrayResource schemaResource = new ByteArrayResource(outStream.toByteArray());
        return schemaResource;
    }

    /**
     * Generate and retrieves all schemas contained into a wsdl file stored in
     * the classpath, in an {@link Resource} array, to be attached to a
     * {@link Jaxb2Marshaller} .
     *
     * @return An {@link Resource} array.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws SAXException
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     * @throws TransformerException
     */
    public Resource[] getSchemas()
        throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        Resource[] schemaResources = null;

        WebServiceClient wscAnnotation = Service.class.getAnnotation(WebServiceClient.class);
        String wsdlLocationPath = wscAnnotation.wsdlLocation();
        Resource wsdlResource = resourceLoader.getResource(wsdlLocationPath);
        URL wsdlUri = wsdlResource.getURL();

        Transformer transformer = newTransformer();
        Document wsdlDoc = loadWsdlDoc(wsdlUri, transformer);
        NodeList schemaNodes = wsdlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI, "schema");
        int nrSchemas = schemaNodes.getLength();
        if (nrSchemas > 0) {
            Element defNode = wsdlDoc.getDocumentElement();
            Map<String, Node> namespaces = getWsdlDefinedNamespaces(defNode);

            schemaResources = new Resource[nrSchemas];

            for (int i = 0; i < nrSchemas; i++) {
                Node schemaNode = schemaNodes.item(i);
                addDefinitionNamespaces(schemaNode, namespaces);
                DOMSource schemaDomSource = updateSchemaLocationByAddingPath(schemaNode);
                schemaResources[i] = transformToResource(schemaDomSource, transformer);
            }
        }

        return schemaResources;
    }
}
```

**applicationContext-xxxx-base.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:mybatis="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
                        http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-spring.xsd">

    <mybatis:scan base-package="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.mybatis.mapper" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.integration.remo" />

    <bean id="xxxxMarshallerProperties" class="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.properties.XxxxMarshallerProperties"/>

    <bean id="xxxxMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" depends-on="xxxxMarshallerProperties">
        <property name="contextPath" value="#{xxxxMarshallerProperties.contextPath}"/>
        <property name="validationEventHandler" value="#{xxxxMarshallerProperties.validationEventHandler}"/>
        <property name="schemas" value="#{xxxxMarshallerProperties.schemas}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="xxxxService" class="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.client.XxxxServiceImpl">
        <property name="defaultUri" value="#{'${xxxx.baseUrl}' + '${xxxx.url.sufix}'}" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="xxxxMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xxxxMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="xxxxObjectFactory" class="com.company.integration.xxxx.domain.model.ObjectFactory" />


</beans>
```

Note that I'm using the Jaxb2Marshaller **schemas**, property (setSchemas), that allow me to set several schemas, instead of only one.